# Highcharts create chart with coloraxis object

Tags: highcharts

I have a code where I create a highcharts chart based upon saved parameters. I create it by first creating an object - which is not the way highcharts advises, but is necessary for my purposes.

I can't seem to find the proper way to pass the colorAxis and it's properties to a chart to be created. Here is what I have tried:

1. The colorAxis as an object on the main chart as just an object.

   thischart.colorAxis={}; 
   thischart.colorAxis.stops=...array of arrays containing info ...
   thischart.colorAxis.min=window[PlotID].colorAxis.min;
   thischart.colorAxis.max=window[PlotID].colorAxis.max;

   ... other parameters ...

   ...new Highcharts.Chart( thischart );
2. The colorAxis as an object on the main chart with an array.

   thischart.colorAxis=new Array();
   thischart.colorAxis['0']={};
   thischart.colorAxis['0'].stops=...array of arrays containing info ...
   thischart.colorAxis['0'].min=window[PlotID].colorAxis.min;
   thischart.colorAxis['0'].max=window[PlotID].colorAxis.max;

   ... other parameters ...

   ...new Highcharts.Chart( thischart );

To be honest, I have been working with this software for months and the lack of documentation is more than frustrating, especially for altering charts that already exist. Am I missing something? Is there a bank of documents other than the main set that explains how to do stuff like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/24qf98xL/

```
options.colorAxis = {};
options.colorAxis.min = 0;
options.colorAxis.minColor ='#FFFFFF';
options.colorAxis.maxColor = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0];

$('#container').highcharts(options);
```

Everything works fine, as you can see.

About docs, official API can be found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis) and all below 'Axis'. If you are using other methods than listed there, then you're using inner methods, which aren't and won't be described.

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have gotten these to work, but I still can't get the stops to work.  Tried options.colorAxis.stops=... with ... being arrays, objects, and text. None of those will work for me.

Comment: OK, So entering the stops as an array works in the fiddle you provided as well. So it appears that my problem is not with the stops but with something else.
Any idea what can cause this error on line 22
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined

Comment: That means you should have somewhere an array but you have null. Could you recreate issue on jsfiddle? Or do you have some demo page live?

Comment: Hey, I found the problem. Apparently, setting the lineWidth parameter causes the heat map to fail. Thanks for your help.